# Calculation operations with the parameters of a TFLite quantized model

Tags: tensorflow, mobilenet, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to implement image classification in hardware using the quantized Mobilenetv2 model taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/hosted_models). To do that, I first need to reproduce the inference process from the beginning to the end to make sure I understand the calculations/operations that are performed on the data.

The first target is the [Conv fuction](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4952f981be07b8bf508f8226f83c10cdafa3f0c4/tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal/reference/reference_ops.h#L248). I can see how it is being calculated, but there are several arguments that are passed to this function which I would like to know how they are produced: `output_offset, output_multiplier,output_shift, output_activation_min, output_activation_max`. I cannot find the previous function that calls the *Conv()* function with these parameters. This would hopefully give me an insight of how these arguments are generated. Could someone point me to the right line of the source code?

Another gap in the sourcecode is at the [interpreter.invoke()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py#L440-L453) function. I wish to track and see what happens next, but can not find the soursecode that implements the *invoke()* function. The help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how the conv reference code is used you can read the code for the [conv operator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/kernels/conv.cc).

The python interpreter uses [swig](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/interpreter_wrapper.i) to call the [C++ intepreter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/interpreter_wrapper.cc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is it! Answer accepted. The calculations are now clear. However, I was still unable to track down where the output scale and output zero point are taken from. I can see that those values are present in the current node `tensors[node->outputs->data[0]]` and the pointer to the node is given to the `Prepare()` function. There there is another place where this node is being populated with all the information including the output scale and offset. Are these two values parsed from the model.tflite file? I can not find them when looking at the node properties via netron.